# Inkscape very slow to start up on Windows

Tags: windows-7, performance, boot, inkscape

I've noticed lately on my Windows 7 x64 PC that [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/) (v0.48.4) is very slow to startup. Once the window becomes visible it will display "Not responding" in the title bar for a minute or two. Once it gets out of this fit it runs normally and smoothly.

I tried deleting the Inkscape user profile (`%APPDATA%\Inkscape`) and that helped for a while. But the problem just appeared again within a week.

Comment: With or without high CPU activity? Inkscape spins a whole CPU core for a minute before it finally shows up here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out the issue was with the Open Recent History. All of the SVG files I open are stored on network shares and move around quite a bit. Disabling this feature resolved the problem permanently. So, I suspect Inkscape verifies and/or reads various information about the files in the Open Recent History.

- **File > Inkscape Preferences** (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
- **Interface**
- Click on **Clear list**
- Set **Maximum documents in Open Recent** to `0`

Comment: I have the same problem, but all of my files are on local drives.

Comment: hmmm, can anyone confirm that this process works for Inkscape 0.92 on Windows 10?  I followed these steps but Inkscape still runs slow on initial loading when I restart it...

Comment: Just tried this and it is indeed a fair bit faster to start, though I had increased the size of the list to 30. I rebooted too, to test cold startup time. Definitely faster, thanks! My files are also all on local drives.

Comment: This worked for me too. I'm on Windows 10 using Inkscape 0.92. As far as I know, all my files are on local drives.

Comment: In my case, any "second" start of inkscape was somewhat faster than the first. Perhaps some of the improvement is based on that as well?

Answer (score 3):

The approach in [Drew Chapin's answer](https://superuser.com/a/783897/31787) made quite a difference on my machine.

Also, startup is slower the more fonts you have installed, according to [this forum discusson](https://forum.inkscapecommunity.com/index.php?topic=660.0):

> I deactivated all fonts that are almost never get used (approx. 2/3 of them). And now Inkscape starts a lot faster.
>
> I wasn't aware I got so much fonts installed, because I did not install them myself. Probably they were automatically included in the install process of some graphic and text applications I use.